# Spring oauth2 /oauth/token causing to call different/another API/method in application

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2, spring-rest

Spring oauth2 `/oauth/token` causing to call different/another API/method in application. I have no clue why is this happening. any help will be appreciated. thanks in advance.

Error:

> {
> "apierror": {
> "status": "BAD_REQUEST",
> "timestamp": "27-06-2021 11:43:25",
> "message": "Malformed JSON request",
> "debugMessage": "Required request body is missing: public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<com.acct.AcctUserVo>
> com.acct.controllers.AcctUserController.register(com.acct.AccountUserRegistrationVo)",
> "subErrors": null
> } }

[image: error]

[image: basic auth]

AcctUserController.java

```
@Controller(Constants.baseApiPath+"account")
@Slf4j
public class AcctUserController {

    @Autowired
    public UserAccountService userAccountService;
    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<AcctUserVo> register(@RequestBody AccountUserRegistrationVo accountUserRegistrationVo){
        AcctUserVo acctUserVo = userAccountService.create(accountUserRegistrationVo);
        ResponseEntity<AcctUserVo> responseEntity = new ResponseEntity(acctUserVo, HttpStatus.OK);
        return responseEntity;
    }


}
```

UserService.java

```
@Service
public class UserService implements UserDetailsService {

    private final UserAccountRepository repository;

    public UserService(UserAccountRepository repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        UserAccount user = repository.findByEmail(username).orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("User not found: " + username));
        GrantedAuthority authority = new SimpleGrantedAuthority("USER");
        return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getEmail(), user.getPassword(), Arrays.asList(authority));
    }
}
```

ResourceServerConfiguration.java

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableResourceServer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configurers.ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer;

@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServerConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) {//tried commenting this method too.
        resources.resourceId("api");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/v1/**").hasAnyAuthority("USER","ANONYMOUS")
                .antMatchers("/oauth/token").permitAll().and().authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated();
    }
}
```

OAuthConfiguration.java

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.configurers.ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableAuthorizationServer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configurers.AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.JwtAccessTokenConverter;

@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class OAuthConfiguration extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    private final UserDetailsService userService;

    @Value("${jwt.clientId:glee-o-meter}")
    private String clientId;

    @Value("${jwt.client-secret:secret}")
    private String clientSecret;

    @Value("${jwt.signing-key:123}")
    private String jwtSigningKey;

    @Value("${jwt.accessTokenValidititySeconds:43200}") // 12 hours
    private int accessTokenValiditySeconds;

    @Value("${jwt.authorizedGrantTypes:password,authorization_code,refresh_token}")
    private String[] authorizedGrantTypes;

    @Value("${jwt.refreshTokenValiditySeconds:2592000}") // 30 days
    private int refreshTokenValiditySeconds;

    public OAuthConfiguration(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager, PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder, UserDetailsService userService) {
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
        this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.inMemory()
                .withClient(clientId)
                .secret(passwordEncoder.encode(clientSecret))
                .accessTokenValiditySeconds(accessTokenValiditySeconds)
                .refreshTokenValiditySeconds(refreshTokenValiditySeconds)
                .authorizedGrantTypes(authorizedGrantTypes)
                .scopes("read", "write")
                .resourceIds("api");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(final AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) {
        endpoints
                .accessTokenConverter(accessTokenConverter())
                .userDetailsService(userService)
                .authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    }

    @Bean
    JwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter() {
        JwtAccessTokenConverter converter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
        return converter;
    }

}
```

ServerSecurityConfig.java

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
//@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, proxyTargetClass = true)
public class ServerSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private final CustomAuthenticationEntryPoint customAuthenticationEntryPoint;

    private final UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    public ServerSecurityConfig(CustomAuthenticationEntryPoint customAuthenticationEntryPoint, @Qualifier("userService")
            UserDetailsService userDetailsService) {
        this.customAuthenticationEntryPoint = customAuthenticationEntryPoint;
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider provider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        provider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        provider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        return provider;
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/signin/**","/oauth/token/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/glee/**").hasAnyAuthority("ADMIN", "USER")
                .antMatchers("/api/users/**").hasAuthority("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/api/**").hasAuthority("USER")
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and().exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(customAuthenticationEntryPoint).accessDeniedHandler(new CustomAccessDeniedHandler());
    }

}
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>



    <groupId>com.app</groupId>
    <artifactId>oauth2</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
          <!--  <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>-->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
      <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <!--<version>2.7.4</version>-->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending 2 good days, found that the below is the problem:

```
@Controller(Constants.baseApiPath+"account")
```

Replaced above with

```
@RestController // not sure if I used @Controller still would have worked. Since it is rest API so changed it. 
@RequestMapping(Constants.baseApiPath+"account")
@PostMapping
public ResponseEntity<AcctUserVo> register(@RequestBody 
AccountUserRegistrationVo accountUserRegistrationVo){
```

Having mentioned above still trying to understand why the this method is called